# Implementation Shibboleth Angular\dotnet

Tags: .net, angular, apache2, shibboleth

I have a web app where the frontend is in angular and the backend is in .net this application manages the login\sign in through Auth0. I should replace auth0 and the federated authentication then, with shibboleth, I have already taken care of uploading the frontend of the application to the apache server, is there any guide on how to implement or could you give me some step by step directions to implement shibboleth? Currently shibboleth is installed on the remote machine where the Apache web server is, within which I need to upload the frontend, can anyone give me some guidance on how to do it and what I need to put in my frontend ??